# I want to make adder tree with chisel 3

Tags: scala, chisel

First of all, I implemented adder which is shown below.

```
class AdderSwitch(InputBandwidth: Int, OutputBandwidth: Int, NumberOfOutputBuffer: Int) extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {

    val InputLeft = Input(SInt(InputBandwidth.W))      
    val InputRight = Input(SInt(InputBandwidth.W))    

    val OutputLeft = Output(SInt(InputBandwidth.W))      
    val OutputSum = Output(SInt(OutputBandwidth.W))
    val OutputRight = Output(SInt(InputBandwidth.W))     

    val PassingOrSum = Input(Bool())

    val OutputLeftReady = Input(Bool())
    val OutputSumReady = Input(Bool())
    val OutputRightReady = Input(Bool())

  })

  val Demux0 = Module(new Demux(InputBandwidth = InputBandwidth))
  Demux0.io.Sel := io.PassingOrSum
  Demux0.io.DemuxInput := io.InputLeft

  val Demux1 = Module(new Demux(InputBandwidth = InputBandwidth))
  Demux1.io.Sel := io.PassingOrSum
  Demux1.io.DemuxInput := io.InputRight

  val OutputSumWire = Wire(SInt(OutputBandwidth.W))
  OutputSumWire := Demux0.io.Output1 + Demux1.io.Output1// + Mux(io.ForwardingMux, io.ForwardRightInput, io.ForwardLeftInput)
  
  val OutputLeftBuffer = Module (new Queue(SInt(), NumberOfOutputBuffer))
  val OutputSumBuffer = Module (new Queue(SInt(), NumberOfOutputBuffer))
  val OutputRightBuffer = Module (new Queue(SInt(), NumberOfOutputBuffer))

  OutputLeftBuffer.io.enq.bits := Mux(io.PassingOrSum, OutputSumWire, Demux0.io.Output0)
  OutputLeftBuffer.io.enq.valid := true.B

  OutputSumBuffer.io.enq.bits := OutputSumWire
  OutputSumBuffer.io.enq.valid := true.B

  OutputRightBuffer.io.enq.bits := Mux(io.PassingOrSum, OutputSumWire, Demux1.io.Output0)
  OutputRightBuffer.io.enq.valid := true.B

  io.OutputLeft := OutputLeftBuffer.io.deq.bits
  io.OutputSum := OutputSumBuffer.io.deq.bits
  io.OutputRight := OutputRightBuffer.io.deq.bits

  OutputLeftBuffer.io.deq.ready := io.OutputLeftReady
  OutputSumBuffer.io.deq.ready := io.OutputSumReady
  OutputRightBuffer.io.deq.ready := io.OutputRightReady

}
```

I checked my code works well when it is tested.

I want to make adder tree which looks like below with chisel 3.[image: binary adder tree]

I was trying to use my adder code as a node of this tree.

So, I decided to use scala library, scala.immutable.collection.

However, there are so many object and class. And, I am very new to this definition.

To implement scala tree data structure for my chisel code, what do I have to do first?

Comment: Have you done the chisel-bootcamp ? https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel-bootcamp

Comment: Yes, i did. Should i read it again?

Comment: The answer to "where to start" is almost always "start with a simpler version of the problem", and then work up from there. For example, your big problem here is to make a whole tree of adders. Are you able to make _one_ adder? If so, show us the code for that, and show us how you tried to take the next step with it, and tell us where you got stuck and what error message or unexpected behavior occurred.

Comment: I'm sorry, i understood that my question was a mess. I am going to edit it. I edited my question.